# Retraining inception model

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I'm trying to retrain tensorflow inception model with my own classes and images following this tutorial:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/inception

It works fine until I deploy the retrained model to tensorflow serving.
When I try to infer, the server returns classes and scores but apparently classes are relevant to original ImageNet dataset.

```
string_val: "black widow, Latrodectus mactans"
string_val: "garden spider, Aranea diademata"
string_val: "hammerhead, hammerhead shark"
string_val: "common iguana, iguana, Iguana iguana"
```

Obviously I need my own classes, though I have no idea how to substitute them.

```
signature_def['predict_images']:
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
inputs['images'] tensor_info:
   dtype: DT_STRING
   shape: (-1)
   name: ParseExample/ParseExample:0
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
outputs['classes'] tensor_info:
   dtype: DT_STRING
   shape: (-1, 5)
   name: index_to_string_Lookup:0
outputs['scores'] tensor_info:
   dtype: DT_FLOAT
   shape: (-1, 5)
   name: TopKV2:0
Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

Here is the SavedModel signature I use. It seems like I have to replace 'classes' lookup with my own before I deploy the model, but I cannot figure out how to do that.

Comment: Are you following the [tensorflow_serving Inception example](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_saved_model.py#L49)? It looks like you could modify `imagenet_lsvrc_2015_synsets.txt` with an ordered list of feature IDs, and `imagenet_metadata.txt` with a mapping from those to human readable labels.

Comment: Thanks @AllenLavoie. It works.